# Angular Resolver -resolving data from HTTP call is not working

Tags: angular, apollo

I'm trying to resolve data from HTTP call from graphql apollo client. The data does not get resolved and the component using the resolver cannot access the data.

In the logs , I can see that the observable is returned first and then data from service is returned.

The data from service - `{name: "s raina", id: "e78903e0-5214-11e8-93f9-8951cc65e163", country: "sa", __typename: "Cricketer", Symbol(id): "Cricketer:e78903e0-5214-11e8-93f9-8951cc65e163"}`

In resolver, instead of returning an observable, I tried returning subscribing to the observable and returning the data. In this case, the component using resolver accesses undefined data after which the service gets the data.

Any help would be appreciated.

Resolver:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { Resolve } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Cricketer } from './types';
import { CricketerService } from './cricketer.service';
import { ActivatedRouteSnapshot } from '@angular/router/src/router_state';
@Injectable()
export class CricketerResolver implements Resolve<any> {
  cricketer: any;
  constructor(private cricketerService: CricketerService) {

  }

  resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot) {
    console.log(this.cricketerService.getCricketer(route.paramMap.get('id')));
    return this.cricketerService.getCricketer(route.paramMap.get('id'));
  }
}
```

Service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Apollo } from 'apollo-angular';
import gql from 'graphql-tag';
import { map , filter } from 'rxjs/operators';

import { Query , Cricketer } from './types';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';
@Injectable()
export class CricketerService {
  constructor(private apollo: Apollo) {}
  private searchInput: BehaviorSubject<String> = new BehaviorSubject<String>('');

  getAllCricketers(searchTerm: String) {
    return this.apollo.watchQuery<Query>({
        pollInterval: 10000,
        query: gql`
        query allCricketers($searchTerm: String){
          allCricketers(searchTerm: $searchTerm){
            name
            id
            country
            age
          }
        }
        `,
        variables: {
          searchTerm: searchTerm
        }
      })
      .valueChanges.pipe(map(result => {
        return result.data.allCricketers;
      }));
  }

  getCricketer(id: String) {
    return this.apollo
      .watchQuery<Query>({
        query: gql`
          query getCricketer($id: String!){
            getCricketer(id: $id) {
              name
              id
              country
            }
          }
      `,
        variables: {
          id: id
        }
      })
      .valueChanges.pipe(map(result => {
        console.log(result.data.getCricketer);
        return result.data.getCricketer;
      }));
  }

  addCricketer(name: String, country: String, age: Number) {
    return this.apollo.mutate({
      mutation: gql`
        mutation addCricketer(name: $name,country: $country, age: $age){
          id
          name
          country
          age
        }
      `,
      variables: {
        name: name,
        country: country,
        age: age
      }
    });
  }

  updateCricketer(id: String, name: String, country: String, age: Number) {
    return this.apollo.mutate({
      mutation: gql`
          mutation updateCricketer(id: $id , name: $name,country: $country, age: $age){
            id
            name
            country
            age
          }
        `,
      variables: {
        id: id,
        name: name,
        country: country,
        age: age
      }
    });
  }

  updateSearchTerm(searchInput: String) {
    this.searchInput.next(searchInput);
  }

  getSearchTerm() {
    return this.searchInput.asObservable();
  }
}
```

Component using resolver:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-cricketer-detail',
  templateUrl: './cricketer-detail.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./cricketer-detail.component.css']
})
export class CricketerDetailComponent implements OnInit {
  cricketer: any;
  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.cricketer = this.route.snapshot.data.cricketer;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Solved this by using the query method instead of watchQuery method. The watchQuery does not complete since it can emit multiple results. So the resolver did not receive the observable and did not resolve the route.

One of the members of the apollo-graphql team

> With query() you fetch data, receive the result, then an Observable
> completes.
>
> With watchQuery() you fetch data, receive the result and an
> Observable is keep opened for new emissions so it never completes.

From Docs

> Apollo.query method returns an Observable that emits a result, just
> once
>
> Apollo.watchQuery also does the same, except it can emit multiple
> results. (The GraphQL query itself is still only sent once, but the
> watchQuery observable can also update if, for example, another query
> causes the object to be updated within Apollo Client’s global cache.)

Ref- https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-angular/issues/280